# Kotlin Map: why is there no toHashMap()?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, `Map` class has `toLinkedMap()` and `toSortedMap()` extension methods.

But why is there no `toHashMap()` method? In fact, the resulting `Map` implementation of many stdlib methods is `LinkedHashMap`, but casting it to `HashMap` in my code would make me rely on the implementation which is bad.

Introducing such a method would keep developers safe from digging into the implementation, and with the current implementation it would just perform the cast.

My use case is:

```
val matchesInClass: HashMap<MessageClass, HashMap<Int, Int>>

//...

for ((cl, matches) in matchesInClass) {
    matchesInClass[cl] = matches.filterKeys { it !in banned } //error: not a HashMap
}
```

When I use `HashMap(matches.filterKeys { it !in banned })` it leads to overhead of creating a new map, which I'd be happy to avoid.

So, is it by design?

Comment: Why do you need second type parameter of matchesInClass to be HashMap and not simply Map or MutableMap?
i.e. have type of matchesInClass to be `HashMap<MessageClass, Map<Int, Int>>`

Comment: @Ilya, `Map` won't go because in  `//...` part I perform edits on values of `matchesInClass`. `MutableMap` doesn't fit either: `filterKeys` returns `Map` which cannot be cast to `MutableMap`.

Comment: Questions that are "why" or "opinion" maybe marked as closed because they are not really asking for a problem to be solved.  You should edit your question to ask about the best ways to create a `toHashMap` function, or alternatives to your given problem (such as filterKeys no returning what you want).  Other places are better to ask status of product features, design decisions, and open ended questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this place in stdlib is inconvenient. But how do you want such a function `toHashMap()` to be implemented?

The simplest implementation makes a cast `as HashMap` if the underlying map is a HashMap, and convert it otherwise. So the performance of that code will dramatically change in case of changing the implementation. That's bad.

So, IMHO, I prefer unsafe cast which fails if `stdlib` changes in a strange way and alerts me of that.

Anyway you are always welcome to report this issue as a ticket in YouTrack  http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT. You gave a prety good description of the problem here, so it shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 2):

**Why?** is hard to answer, but searching for or adding a ticket to [Kotlin issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) will get you that answer as well as update you when the status changes. It does seem that `toHashMap` is missing since `toHashSet` is there (as-of 1.0 BETA 4).

**Note:** that LinkedHashMap is the default because kotlin wants to maintain order of elements as you go from `List` to `Set` to `List` to `Map` to `List` and be sure that things are still in their relative order.

Regardless, In the meantime, here is a custom `toHashMap` for you:

```
public fun <K, V> Iterable<Pair<K, V>>.toHashMap(): Map<K, V>
    = HashMap<K, V>(collectionSizeOrNull() ?: 16).apply { putAll(this@toHashMap) }
```

You can make it better by using logic similar to the `toMap` function for picking the best initial map size, or don't set it and trust the default growth implementation.

Kotlin is built to easily be extended.  If everything is placed into the stdlib then people on constrainted devices such as Android will complain it is too big and really most things people ask for that are small oddities are a few lines of code to put into your own custom lib.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer to your original question, but an alternative solution to your use case.

Here you're trying to filter `HashMap<Int, Int>` and assign it back to the map it was taken from:

> matchesInClass[cl] = matches.filterKeys { it !in banned } //error: not a HashMap

If you have no requirement to keep `matches` HashMap intact, you could filter it in-place by invoking `removeAll` function on its `keys` mutable set:

```
val matchesInClass: HashMap<MessageClass, HashMap<Int, Int>>

//...

for (matches in matchesInClass.values) {
    matches.keys.removeAll { it in banned } // notice the inverted condition
}
```

It would be more efficient than creating a filtered copy.

Another alternative would be to use `Map.filterTo` provided with an empty map of the required type:

```
for (entry in matchesInClass) {
    entry.setValue(entry.value.filterTo(HashMap()) { it !in banned })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just filter it like this:

`val filtered = matchesInClass.mapValues { it.value.filterKeys { it !in banned } }`